# Using Dispel magic on Cleric's Divine Domain: Shadow, Favor of Darkness ability

Tags: dnd-5e, cleric, divine

Text on Dispel magic

> Choose one creature, object, or magical effect within range. Any spell
>   of 3rd level or lower on the target ends. For each spell of 4th level
>   or higher on the target, make an ability check using your spellcasting
>   ability. The DC equals 10 + the spell’s level. On a successful check,
>   the spell ends.

Text on Favor of Darkness

> Starting at 2nd level, by presenting your holy symbol and spending a
>   use of Channel Divinity, you can flood a 30-foot radius centered on
>   you with magical shadows.

I can add more relevant text if needed but I could add some if needed.

I don't see any spell level associated with it but it is definitely a magical effect.  Can this be dispelled?  Why/Why not?  Are there any checks associated with dispelling this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No. It is not a spell effect. Dispel magic only works on *spell* effects, not on other magical effects.

the text for dispel magic even though saying "choose an effect", that is the target. As for the effect of dispel, it is:

> Any spell of 3rd level or lower on the target ends.

Choose an effect here means an effect like the parts of a [Guards and Wards](http://engl393-dnd5th.wikia.com/wiki/Guards_and_Wards) spell, that can be dispelled individually:

> A dispel magic cast on a specific effect, if successful, removes only that effect.

Since that cleric effect is not a spell, dispel magic is just wasted. The DM should let the caster know that it cannot be dispelled (either before or after the dispel magic, depending on DM discretion) as opposed to just "dispel magic failed".

Comment: Interesting.  I did not realize that dispel magic ONLY worked on spells and not magic.

Comment: @dphil this is particular to 5e. If I recall right, in 3.x (almost) every effect had a caster level and was possible to dispel. But tradition mandated the spell retained its name, even though now it is a "Dispel Spell" *spell*.